# How to Run 'Before' Case only once for multiple threads

Tags: junit, jmeter, junit4

I have a Junit Test Sampler that has to run with 100 threads, but i want the before case for the same to run only once. How can i do this scenario?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter), it should help you...

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
@Override
public void setUp(){
    JMeterContext ctx = JMeterContextService.getContext();
    JMeterVariables vars = ctx.getVariables();
    if (ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 && vars.getIteration()==1) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Will trigger your setup code only for 1st thread and 1st iteration.

References:

- [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
- [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Add your samplers under Once Only controller. They will be executed only once for each thread and should solve your problem.

You can refer to http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller